# The change event is not triggered before the beforeunloadhow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are lots of questions about the "beforeunload" event and I think I read most of them. So I wrote the following code to warn a user about leaving a page before saving data, and it works most of the time.

It does not work when the user enters a value in input "f1" and leaves the page before tabbing out of the "f1". In that case the beforeunload event triggers before the change event and no warning is issued.

How should I modify the code?

thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var g_page_changed = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
        if (g_page_changed) {
            return 'Do you really want to leave without saving?' ; 
        }
    });

    $('input').change(function() {
        g_page_changed = true;
    });
});
</script>
<form id="frm">
 <input id="f1" name="f1" type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: As per the documentation, `change` is only fired on blur. You'd want `keydown` for example instead of `change`. http://api.jquery.com/change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change event isn't triggered until the input field has been `blur`d, so triggering a `blur` on your input before the conditional should fix it:

```
var g_page_changed = false;


$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    $('input').blur();
        if (g_page_changed) {
            return 'Do you really want to leave without saving?' ;
        }
    });

  $('input').change(function() {
        g_page_changed = true;
    });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/XhT26/

Comment: Perfect. That did it. I can use that logic other places too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MAybe you should use keypress() instead of change() and put some additional logic in it.

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length > 0){
         g_page_changed = true;
    }else{
         g_page_changed = false;
    }
});
```

With this code you check if the lemgth of the input field is > 0 and then set the variable to true or otherwise (if the user cancelled all he entered) check it back to false. Look around for jquery plugins that check for 'dirtieness' of inputs if the input field has alredy some text in when the pages load.

The change event is triggered only when the input fields lose focus, i think.

Comment: Thank you, I thought if that. So I thought does that add too much overhead. Also they may not actually change any data with a keypress.

Comment: i edited my code with an example to take account of the fact that the user can 'erase' data, anyway i don't think you would have great problems of overhead (when you use counters you do something similar to this)

Comment: Thanks, I agree about the overhead.